# Write "<" or ">" to a .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I want to write "<" or ">" symbol to a text files.
There's an examle of what I tried:

```
echo echo. >file2.txt>file1.txt
```

But that doesn't work.
What I want is to make the batch file make file2.txt with this text below:

```
echo. >file1.txt
```

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the `<` or `>` using `^`. Note to actually redirect to a file, you'll need an extra redirect operator.

Here's an example using `>` - the same solution works for `<` (and `%` as well).

```
echo .^> > file.txt
```

So to get the results you want (a text file containing `echo. file2.txt > file1.txt`) in a text file named *redir.txt*:

```
echo echo. file2.txt ^> file1.txt > redir.txt
```

The end result in *redir.txt*:

```
c:\temp>type redir.txt
echo. file2.txt > file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there is a way to do that. Nothing is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Is this DOS? Look here:

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

you have to use a caret "^". echo ^>

PHP use a \

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Is it Unix? Use quotes.

Comment: The [batch-file] tag is exclusive to Windows shell scripting, but nice comprehensive answer.